# How is G. B. Shaw's Caesar and Cleopatra (1898) different from the eponymous characters' true relationship?

Tags: historical-context, george-bernard-shaw, caesar-and-cleopatra

I know that Shaw's play is a fictionalized account of Caesar and Cleopatra's relationship. But how is G. B. Shaw's Caesar and Cleopatra (1898) different from the eponymous characters' true relationship?

Comment: Would it help to read them both – Shaw's work and a historical account of Caeser and Cleopatra's relationship – and then return with your answer???? I am tempted to do that myself, but I need to find the time.